# Solr score is not sorted correctly

Tags: sorting, solr

The sorting on score is not longer correct.

textfield setup:

```
<!-- Danish -->
    <fieldType name="text_da" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Danish"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_da.txt" format="snowball" /> 
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>    
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>       
        <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="Danish"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_da.txt" format="snowball" />     
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

handler:

```
<requestHandler name="/solarquery" class="solr.SearchHandler">
     <lst name="defaults">
       <str name="echoParams">all</str>
       <str name="wt">json</str>
       <str name="indent">true</str>
       <str name="df">text</str>
       <!-- Query settings -->
       <str name="defType">edismax</str>
       <str name="mm">100%</str>
       <str name="q.alt">*:*</str>
       <str name="rows">10</str>
       <str name="fl">*,score</str>
       <str name="facet">on</str>
       <int name="facet.limit">10</int>
       <int name="facet.mincount">1</int>
       <str name="facet.field">category</str>
       <str name="facet.field">brand_exact</str>
       <str name="facet.field">articletype</str>
       <str name="facet.field">oncw</str>
       <str name="facet.field">concepts</str>
       <str name="facet.field">features</str>
     </lst>
     <arr name="last-components">
      <str>elevator</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

When I run a basic query like: solarquery?q=toilet&wt=json&sort=score desc&indent=true&debugQuery=true

The score is not sorted correctly:

```
(MATCH) sum of:\n  2.6150227 =,...
(MATCH) sum of:\n  3.1380272 =,...
(MATCH) sum of:\n  3.1380272 =,...
(MATCH) sum of:\n  3.1380272 =,...
(MATCH) sum of:\n  3.1380272 =,...
(MATCH) sum of:\n  2.9585605 =,...
(MATCH) sum of:\n  2.9585605 =,...
(MATCH) sum of:\n  2.9585605 =,...
(MATCH) sum of:\n  2.9585605 =,...
(MATCH) sum of:\n  2.9585605 =,...
```

I think the problem has someting to do with the handler, but I do not know what the problem is?

Rgds Leif

Answer (score 0):

- check your query elevation file, maybe the first document is included in the `elevate.xml` file. If you want try without the elevator component and see if it makes a difference, that will be also a good test.
- also you don't have to mention sort=score desc, as this is the default behaviour.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the elevate file, it did contain the top document, that did not match the sort. Thanks a lot.